# Javascript - Function to Count Unique Database Rows

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I am writing a Javascript function where I need to count the number of unique entry in a certain column in my SQLite Database. So far, what I have tried to do is to just simply count the number of entries present as I need that as a parameter when I populate entries. My function goes as such:

```
MasterTreeDB.transaction(function(transaction) {
    transaction.executeSql("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MasterTreeTable", [],
        function(transaction, result) {
            //console.log(result.rows);
            console.log(result.rows.item(0));
        },
        function(transaction, error){
            // error occured
            console.log("Error occured");

        }
    );
});
```

However, this is what the console shows: `Object {COUNT(*): 4}`

I have also looked around and I saw a solution that involved changing `results.row.item(0)` to `results.row.item(0)["count(*)"]`. However, when I did that, the log showed `undefined`

I feel like I'm really close to getting the result I want and I'm missing something rather basic. Any help/input is very much appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Try grouping by the column. example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6744803/sqlite-count-group-and-order-by-count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"count the number of unique entry in a certain column in my SQLite Database":

```
select TheColumn from MasterTreeTable group by TheColumn;
```

Then `result.rows.length` is the number of unique values contained in `TheColumn`.